# How to redirect after HttpRequest POST?

Tags: httprequest, redirect, post

In a Visualforce controller, if I need to do an HTTP POST and redirect to that same URL, how do I do it?

Here's the situation: currently the client has a plain HTML form (standard HTML form and input tags) that submits search criteria fields directly to a 3rd party search web site. This appears in a new window and displays a list of results.

They want a custom button on the Salesforce account detail page to submit account fields as search criteria to the external website. It should still open a new window to show the results

Question is: once the controller sends the HTTPRequest, how do I redirect to the external web page with the results?  Do I instantiate a PageReference with the HttpResponse body, or just use the original URL?